# Need to have the full word come back instead of just the first letter

Tags: python, sorting, ascii

```
##Write a program that inputs a text file. 
##The program should print the unique words in the file in alphabetical order. 
##Uppercase words should take precedence over lowercase words. For example, 'Z' comes before 'a'.
## The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

    file_words = open("Words.txt", 'r+')
    words_list = []
    first_val_list = []

    for line in file_words:
        for word in line.split():
            words_list.append(word)

    for word in words_list:
        first_val = word[0]
        ascii = ord(first_val)
        first_val_list.append(first_val)

    first_val_list.sort(reverse=False)
```

Now this outputs ['T', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'j', 'l', 'o', 'q', 't'], which is what I need it to do but with the entire word.
For Example,
['The', 'brown', 'dog', 'fox', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'over', 'quick', 'the']

The print of the first_val_list was just to see if what I had so far was working.
So how would I get the full word back onto the first letter
I'm new to programming in general and have around 10 weeks experience so explain like I'm 5 please.

Comment: What do you think `first_val = word[0]` does?  Why do you compute `ascii` if you never use it?

Comment: Your code looks like `Python`, so I added the tag. If I'm wrong, please put in the correct one.

Comment: What does "print the unique words in the file" mean? If a word has duplicates in the text file, does it mean you should not print it at all? Or print it but only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_val` is the first letter of the word. So you're only putting the first letter into the list, rather than the whole word.

You're also not removing duplicates. You can do this by converting the list of words to a set.

```
with open("words.txt") as file_words:
    words_list = file_words.read().split()

unique_words = set(words_list)
sorted_words = sorted(unique_words)
```